# Constraints set on xib file not working for ipad ios

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I have an app that I want to run on iphone and ipad. I am using xib files and auto layout. The layout is perfect for all iphone simulators, but not for ipad. I have a UIImageView that covers the whole screen, and I want it to completely cover all screens of iphone and ipad. So I set the following constraints:

[image]

Where new_BG.png is the background UIImageView.

But when I run the app on ipad simulator the image only covers part of the screen. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

What constraints do I need to add for the image to cover the whole screen?
Picture of xib:
[image]

One more thing. I tried setting the frame of the image view in code by making it equal to the height and width of the screen size like the following:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
new_BG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

But it still only covers the top left of the screen when running on ipad. Then I changed the width and height to 100 and still no change when running on ipad.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the xib.

Comment: Okay adding an image of xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your constraint set is redundant - you can replace .centerX and .centerY constraints with single one relation: **new_BG.png.bottom - Superview.Bottom**
2. UIImageView might display its UIImage this way if it has Mode property set to Top Left.
3. Since your UI elements have wrong layout as well I think the problem isn't only with UIImageView (if only your image contains UI elements depicted on itself)

Comment: Okay I fixed constraints. The UIImageview is set to scale to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give any center constraints like center x or center y. Just give `leading,trailing,bottom and top`. this will cover full screen on both iphone and ipad.

and i thing there is custom navigation bar you are using by uiview. so give constraint to it like - `leading,trailing,top and fix height`

hope this will work.